# Hibernate - Delete by NaturalID

Tags: hibernate

I was wondering, Is there any way for deleting an entity by Hibernate using
its naturalID - annotated fields.

I know there's a way for loading with them (by the Session.getByNaturalID/Session.getBySimpleNaturalID methods)

My point deleting an entity which for I dont know it's ID.
I dont want to query the DB just for the ID, and dont want to write
a delete HQL, which is not so flexible for changes (removing fieds, ect.)

So, is there such a way?
Is it even reasonable to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below Criteria API code where natural-id can be provided as restriction. [CriteriaDelete](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaDelete.html) can be used to delete entities.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();  
CriteriaDelete<XEntity> deleteXEntity = cb.createCriteriaDelete(XEntity.class);
deleteXEntity.where(Restrictions.naturalId().set("fieldName", "xyz"));
entityManager.createQuery(deleteXEntity).executeUpdate();
```

---

**Edit:**

Added code to add restriction for available natural id's; without setting them explicitly.

```
    CLassMetaData entityMetaData = session.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(XEntity.class);

    int[] naturalIds = entityMetaData.getNaturalIdentifierProperties();
    String[] propertyNames = entityMetaData.getPropertyNames();

    for(Object o : deleteObjects){

       for(int i=0; i<naturalIds.length ; i++){

          Object xPropertyValue = getPropertyValue(o, propertyNames[i], EntityMode.POJO);

          if(xPropertyValue != null)
           Restrictions.naturalId().set(propertyNames[i], xPropertyValue);

           //-- Add restrictions
       }
    //-- Delete object with all restrictions
   }
```

*[This is pseudo-code, can make changes accordingly; I haven't tried it.]*

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really helping me.
It's not much different than writing an HQL, but the caching matters.
I dont want to set any of the naturalID fields.
Hibernate supposed to know what my naturalID fields are, and what are the values from the entity, just like it does with the regular ID...

Comment: @user3027497 I have added sample code to identify natural ids & then deleting based on those, can refer edit part.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I did at the end
But isn't it doing Hibernate's job?

Comment: @user3027497 Yes, there should be some functionality like this in-built. I don't know exactly if that can be requested or you can add that in some release.